# How to test for 3 or more items in Minecraft inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a town in Minecraft, and I want to add a currency system. I know you can test for exactly a certain number with /execute; however, it's very annoying to have to sort out  EXACTLY the amount needed to buy something. 
So my question: Is there a way to test for 3 *or more* of an item? Like, if you're holding 64 currency and the item you're buying costs 3?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is use some form of container for a player to put the currency into and then use a repeating command block with always active on and then put in the command

```
replaceitem blocks <pos:x y z> slot.container <container slot number> currency 3
```

Then put a chain command block in front of the arrow on the repeating command block and set it to: conditional then put in the command

```
replaceitem @p <slot number> 61
```

And just have a whole set of command blocks that just give back however much they put in - however much it costs = result, or just use a villager to sell stuff to people but by giving it custom trades look to the wiki for this or use xp as currency and again look at the wiki for this one as well

Comment: Those two commands don't even work. I also don't know what you're trying to accomplish with them, they surely do not count items.

Comment: They don't count them, but they replace the incorrect number of currency with the correct amount and gives back the amount they had minus the correct amount of currency

Comment: The commands work i've used them idk how many times

Comment: Certainly not. Both "`/replaceitem blocks`" and "`replaceitem @p`" are not the beginning of any valid command.

Comment: Yes it is, i've done it god knows how many times

Comment: You've just never tried using them or seen them

Comment: Just look at the wiki! Those commands do not exist! If you have working commands, then directly copy them from the game instead of re-typing, because you've obviously made typos.